# Schrodinger’s Cat Observer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, schroedingers-cat

Will there be different observance of dead and alive cat to different observer, at the same time?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question and give more information.

Comment: You can check this link: @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this is attracting *Needs details or clarity* close votes as it seems clear to me. The question is asking if two observers can simultaneously measure the same quantum system to be in different states.

Comment: The solution to all Schrodinger's Cat problems : stop using the awful thought experiment that has confused generations of physicists (and cats). :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. At a given time, the cat must be alive if it is not dead- that does not vary by observer.

Comment: According to this theory When a cat is inside box its either dead or alive. 
If you check inside the box the one of the thing(i.e either dead or alive) will be reality so in this case if two different person checks inside the box and the answer they get is kept secret to other observer can the result vary can the reality vary ??

Comment: No, it cannot vary!!!!! Reality is reality.

Comment: Then how can we say that the cat is both dead or alive inside box thats just assumption but reality is its either dead or alive isn’t it